# Long-Press Touchevents

Tags: java, android

I have three buttons that are tapped based on touchevents in a certain boundary and I want to change it so that the tapevents can be a long-press instead of a tap. I'm not sure how to do this. Here is my relevant code:

```
private void updateRunning(List<TouchEvent> touchEvents, float deltaTime) {
// 1. All touch input is handled here:
int len = touchEvents.size();
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
TouchEvent event = touchEvents.get(i);

if (event.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_DOWN) {

if (inBounds(event, 340,512,140,140)) {
 B1Pressed = true;
 Log.d("GameScreen", "Button 1 Pressed");
// Button 1
}

if (inBounds(event, 340,320,140,140)) {
 B2Pressed = true;
 Log.d("GameScreen", "Button 2 Pressed");
 // Button 2
 }

if (inBounds(event, 340,120,140,140)) {
  B3Pressed = true;
  Log.d("GameScreen", "Button 3 Pressed");
 // Button 3
 }

 }

 private boolean inBounds(TouchEvent event, int x, int y, int width,
        int height) {
    if (event.x > x && event.x < x + width - 1 && event.y > y
            && event.y < y + height - 1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Input.java:

```
 public interface Input {

public static class TouchEvent {
    public static final int TOUCH_DOWN = 0;
    public static final int TOUCH_UP = 1;
    public static final int TOUCH_DRAGGED = 2;
    public static final int TOUCH_HOLD = 3;

    public int type;
    public int x, y;
    public int pointer;


}

public boolean isTouchDown(int pointer);

public int getTouchX(int pointer);

public int getTouchY(int pointer);

public List<TouchEvent> getTouchEvents();
}
```

TouchHandler.java:

```
public interface TouchHandler extends OnTouchListener {
public boolean isTouchDown(int pointer);

public int getTouchX(int pointer);

public int getTouchY(int pointer);

public List<TouchEvent> getTouchEvents();
}
```

SingleTouchHandler:

```
 public class SingleTouchHandler implements TouchHandler {
boolean isTouched;
int touchX;
int touchY;
Pool<TouchEvent> touchEventPool;
List<TouchEvent> touchEvents = new ArrayList<TouchEvent>();
List<TouchEvent> touchEventsBuffer = new ArrayList<TouchEvent>();
float scaleX;
float scaleY;

public SingleTouchHandler(View view, float scaleX, float scaleY) {
    PoolObjectFactory<TouchEvent> factory = new PoolObjectFactory<TouchEvent>() {
        @Override
        public TouchEvent createObject() {
            return new TouchEvent();
        }            
    };
    touchEventPool = new Pool<TouchEvent>(factory, 100);
    view.setOnTouchListener(this);

    this.scaleX = scaleX;
    this.scaleY = scaleY;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    synchronized(this) {
        TouchEvent touchEvent = touchEventPool.newObject();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touchEvent.type = TouchEvent.TOUCH_DOWN;
            isTouched = true;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touchEvent.type = TouchEvent.TOUCH_DRAGGED;
            isTouched = true;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:                
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touchEvent.type = TouchEvent.TOUCH_UP;
            isTouched = false;
            break;
        }

        touchEvent.x = touchX = (int)(event.getX() * scaleX);
        touchEvent.y = touchY = (int)(event.getY() * scaleY);
        touchEventsBuffer.add(touchEvent);                        

        return true;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean isTouchDown(int pointer) {
    synchronized(this) {
        if(pointer == 0)
            return isTouched;
        else
            return false;
    }
}

@Override
public int getTouchX(int pointer) {
    synchronized(this) {
        return touchX;
    }
}

@Override
public int getTouchY(int pointer) {
    synchronized(this) {
        return touchY;
    }
}

@Override
public List<TouchEvent> getTouchEvents() {
    synchronized(this) {     
        int len = touchEvents.size();
        for( int i = 0; i < len; i++ )
            touchEventPool.free(touchEvents.get(i));
        touchEvents.clear();
        touchEvents.addAll(touchEventsBuffer);
        touchEventsBuffer.clear();
        return touchEvents;
    }
}
}
```

How can I go about implementing long press?

Answer (score 0):

Let your Class Implement  View.OnLongClickListener as

```
  SingleTouchHandler Implements View.OnLongClickListener
      @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    return false;
    }
```

and you get method to perform long press opertaions hope this helps